# Stack new Stages instead of overlaying

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I create multiple Stages at once like this

```
for (Object o : tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())
{
    if (o != null)
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader  fxmlLoader  = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui/fxml/Stage.fxml"));
            Parent      root1;

            root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The stages arrange on one position so they are overlaying.

Screenshot of overlaying stages:
[image: Screenshot of overlaying stages]

My goal is to stack them similar like Windows alerts like this:

Stacked stages:
[image: Stacked stages]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: seems like your `stage` is being overrided within the loop. Are you seeing only the last alert windows ?

Comment: @Edilson No, every Window appears. However they are on the exact same position so it looks like only one Window is active.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `stage.setX()` and `.setY()` you can achieve this easily if you keep incrementing the x and y value consistently like so

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        int x = 400;
        int y = 400;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            VBox vBox = new VBox();
            vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            vBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("ALERT!!! ALERT!!!"), new Label("Label #:"+i));

            Stage stage  = new Stage();
            stage.setX(x);
            stage.setY(y);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
            stage.show();

            x+=20;
            y+=20;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works pretty good. I've added `stage.centerOnScreen()` after `stage.show()` and used `stage.setX(stage.getX() + x)` to keep the initially location of the window.

Comment: If this answer satisfies the question click the check next to it to accept the answer so others no longer think this question is still open